# Given an array A[] and a number x, check for pair in A[] with sum as x

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given an array A[] and a number x, check for pair in A[] with sum as x. can anyone help me out on this one in rails?

Comment: write the instances, please

Comment: elaborate with an input in array and some pair which you want to check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ruby array `#combination` method can give you all combinations of array members of a given number of elements.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].combination(2).to_a
=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [1, 5], [1, 6], [2, 3], [2, 4], ... [5,6]]
```

Then you just want to select the elements where they add up to a given number.

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]combination(2).to_a.select{|comb| comb[0] + comb[1] == 7}
=> [[1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]]
```

To make it work for a different number of combined elements (e.g. 3 instead of 2) you can do...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]combination(3).to_a.select{|c| (c.inject(0) {|sum,x| sum + x})  == 7}
```

This will work for 2, 3, 4, or any number up to the full array size.

It works by

1. finding combinations of 3
2. using `#inject' to sum all the elements of each combination
3. comparing that sum to the target number

Comment: well, thankyou for your inputs. how should I approach this prob if I had to find triplets instead of pairs.

Comment: Edited the answer to show triplets.  If the answer is satisfactory, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve it by own function as:

```
def sum_as_x?(ary,x)
  num=a.find{|e| ary.include?(x-e)}
  unless num
   puts "not exist"
  else
   p [x-num,num]
 end
end
```

a = [1,2,3,4,5]

sum_to_x?(a,9)

## >> [5, 4]

sum_to_x?(a,20)

## >> not exist

Comment: can I do this for triplets @AmmY